# AngularJS: Load JSON data with bindings in place, doesn't keep any bindings

Tags: angularjs, javascript-databinding

Say I attempt to store an object as plain text that features many model - view bindings with a rather simple function.

```
$http.post("storeJSON.php", {
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.data),
        title: $scope.title
    }
})
```

$scope.data contains all the data my AngularJS app needs to render a particular view.

I used JSON.stringify to keep $$HashKey in an attempt to keep model - view bindings for later use. Aka a Save feature. I pick up back this object in another function.

```
$http.post("getJSON.php", {
        data: {
            path: path
        }
    }).then(res => {
        $scope.data = angular.fromJson(JSON.parse(res.data));
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
```

Expected result? Reload the same view later by fetching this same $scope.data variable intact. It displays all values, except it's missing the bindings from when it was first created. $$HashKeys are still there but do nothing by themselves.

Comment: You never want to store the `$$` properties like `$$HashKeys`. `fromJson()` expects a json string and is the same concept as `JSON.parse()` . As for the bindings I suspect problem has to do with your view. Create a [mcve] that displays your issue

Comment: Also better to let `$http` stingify your json as it will remove the `$$` keys

Comment: What if I want to keep them? I am looking for a way to keep data binded together, there are two arrays within an object , those two arrays originally keep some items binded between each array. I want to export and reimport that data object and retain those relationships. They break right after reimporting, even with the $$HashKeys there.

Comment: Can't help without seeing a working demo. There simply isn't enough code shown to help solve this